# How can I communicate with 2 reactjs components - using Jotai

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, message-passing, jotai

I have 2 reactjs files:

- Reports.js (used to request report and display the result)
- AuthContext.js (has a socket connection to maintain communication with the backend server)

user first goes to the report page generated by Reports.js and then there is a call to the backend server which returns right away but it shows a loading spinner. When the report is completed, it will send the data to AuthContext.js. However, I have trouble from AuthContext.js to be able to request a call setReportLoading() in Reports.js for the purpose of stopping the loading spinner. can you please advise how to solve this ?

I tried the method below setReportLoading() but it has this error:

```
setReportLoading.js:115 Uncaught TypeError: setReportLoading is not a function
```

here is my code snippet

```
In file AuthContext.js
import { setReportLoading } from 'Reports';

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

            socket.on('processmessage', (msg) => {
              if (msg.type == 'checking'){
                  setReportLoading(2);         
              }            
            }); 
   
}

In file Reports.js

const Reports = () => {

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(1)

    const setReportLoading = (isLoading) => {
        setLoading(isLoading);
      };

      const renderContent = () => {

        if (loading === 1) return (
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style={{ minHeight: '200px' }}>
                <div className="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
                    <span className="visually-hidden">{t('loc_react_loading')}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )


        if (loading === 2) return (
            <div className="mb-4 card border-0 shadow-sm" style={{'min-width': '900px'}}>
                {renderReportSelection()}
                {showReport && renderReport()}
            </div>   
        )
    }


    return (
        <DashboardLayout>
        </DashboardLayout>
    )
}

export default Reports;
```

### UPDATE tried using jotai 2.0.0 but somehow no crash, but it didnt seem to go to handleReportloadingChange() function

```
in AuthContext.js

import { atom, useAtom } from 'jotai';

export const reportloadingAtom = atom(1);

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [reportloading, setReportloading] = useAtom(reportloadingAtom);

  socket.on('processmessage', (msg) => {
    if (msg.type == 'checking') {
      setReportloading(2);
    }
  });

  // ...
};

in Reports.js

import { useAtom } from 'jotai';
import { reportloadingAtom } from 'AuthContext'

const Reports = () => {
  const [reportloading, setReportloading] = useAtom(reportloadingAtom);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    // This function will run every time the value of reportloadingAtom changes
    function handleReportloadingChange() {
      console.log("handleReportloadingChange")
      setLoading(reportloading);
    }

  }, [reportloading]);

  // ...
};
```

Comment: Instead of trying to mish/mash React to handle cross component state, don't use React's built in state, it's really only meant for component level state.  When you want anything remotely more complicated a 3rd party state manager is a must.   A really simple one to understand and implement is Jotia,. -> https://jotai.org/

Comment: @Keith I strongly disagree with the statement "a 3rd party state manager is a must". The Context API is more then capable to handle something like a global loading state. Always use React API's before adding another package to your bundle.

Comment: Thanks, I will check out Jotai. @Keith, can you show or link a possible example or tutorial ?

Comment: @Axil  The website has some good examples,.  Basically `atom` & `useAtom` work pretty much like `useState`.   You can then just pass `atom`'s in props, or even `Contexts`.  Not only is this much easier to reason about than passing state up, it will also help with performance.  In the long run using something like Jotai will really help keep React slick, and doing it now rather than later IMO makes total sense even if Fabio doesn't agree.. :).  React not having built in global State has always been it's biggest let down.. :(

Comment: Put `reportloading` as a dependancy on the `useEffect` otherwise the effect won't rerun regardless if the atom changes..

Comment: updated and put in the dependency [reportloading] but still does not work. I'll put in the bounty soon. Just want to get this working. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing is calling `handleReportloadingChange`  you have just created a function inside the effect that you never run.  Not really 100% sure what your trying to do.  I'm not even sure you need the `useEffect` in the first place as your are using an atom,  just do `if (reportloading) { /*...dowhatever, eg. */  return <div>Loading..</div>}`

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can export or import a function declared inside a React component without a third party lib. What you can do is pass it as a props to a child component.

Given the code you have shared, I would sugest you refactor your AuthProvider to a regular function, and not a React component. I suggest this because I dont see your AuthProvider as a child of your Reports component. You can then call this function within your Reports component and have it return some value to then change the vaue of your loading.

Comment: I think its the other way round where Reports is probably the child of AuthProvider. I'm not sure really, but I saw this code in App.js, I just paste it here https://jsfiddle.net/w38p5kLe/